# template class c++

Tags: c++, templates

i try to design a template for my university project. i wrote the follwing code:

```
#ifndef _LinkedList_H_
#define _LinkedList_H_
#include "Link.h"
#include <ostream>
template <class L>//error one
class LinkedList
{
private:
 Link<L> *pm_head;
 Link<L> * pm_tail;
 int m_numOfElements;
 Link<L>* FindLink(L * dataToFind);
public:
 LinkedList();
 ~LinkedList();
 int GetNumOfElements(){return m_numOfElements;}
 bool Add( L * data);
 L *FindData(L * data);

template <class L> friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& os,const LinkedList<L> listToprint);//error two
   L* GetDataOnTop();
   bool RemoveFromHead();
   L* Remove(L * toRemove);
```

this templete uses the link class templete

```
#ifndef _Link_H_
#define _Link_H_
template <class T>//error 3
class Link
{
private:
 T* m_data;
 Link* m_next;
 Link* m_prev;
public:
 Link(T* data);
 ~Link(void);
 bool Link::operator ==(const Link& other)const;

 /*getters*/
 Link* GetNext()const {return m_next;}
 Link* GetPrev()const {return m_prev;}
 T* GetData()const {return m_data;}
 //setters
 void SetNext(Link* next) {m_next = next;}
 void SetPrev(Link* prev) {m_prev = prev;}
 void SetData(T* data) {m_data = data;}

};

error one: shadows template parm `class L'
error two:declaration of `class L'
error three: shadows template parm `class T'
```

i dont understand what is the problem. i can really use your help
thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

These error messages really belong together:

```
a.cc:41: error: declaration of ‘class L’
a.cc:26: error:  shadows template parm ‘class L’
```

This means that in line 41, you introduce a template parameter L; in my copy, this refers to

```
template <class L> friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& os,
               const LinkedList<L> listToprint);//error two
```

And that declaration shadows the template parameter in line 26:

```
template <class L>//error one
class LinkedList
```

You need to rename the template parameter in the friend declaration.

**Edit**: The relevant language specification is 14.6.1/7

> A template-parameter shall not be
>   redeclared within its scope (including
>   nested scopes). A template-parameter
>   shall not have the same name as the
>   template name.

When you refer to `L` in `const LinkedList<L> listToprint`, it's not clear whether you mean the L of the friend or the L of the class. So write

```
template <class L1> friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& os,
    const LinkedList<L1> listToprint);
```

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what i need to rename and why?

Comment: Also consider changing the `friend` template function for a plain non-templated `friend`. You do not need (nor want) to provide access to your class internals (in this case `LinkedList<A>` for a particular type `A`) to all instantiations of a templated `operator<<`. You only need `operator<<( ostream&, const LinkedList<A> & )` to access the class. Note that `A` is *general* for the discussion, but this is not a place holder, but a particular type (`int`, or `double`, but a concrete one of them)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the

```
 template <class L>
```

from the `friend` member function declaration.

You also need to replace uses of `ostream` with `std::ostream` unless you have a `using namespace std` somewhere in your code.

Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: @inna karpasas: It is hard without the whole code to test, but @nimrodm answer is right. You probably don't want to befriend a templated `operator<<` but a single `operator<<` that takes the appropriate types. The reason for the next error you are getting can be about anything that is not shown in the question that confuses the parser.